# Create new keyboard, mouse, or other input value that is unused by all other applications

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, mouse, discord, razer-synapse

My mouse has a [few extra buttons](https://content.screencast.com/users/bens1/folders/Jing/media/75b10b56-4de8-4ba9-9ada-094341057c24/2017-05-20_1849.png) that can be [mapped to keyboard or mouse inputs](https://content.screencast.com/users/bens1/folders/Jing/media/c631fbd7-f48d-4cd4-98e4-5c44ae55d3d4/2017-05-20_1855.png). I use one of those buttons to activate my microphone. I've [mapped the mouse button to the `break` key](https://content.screencast.com/users/bens1/folders/Jing/media/3d826e9a-9d1c-4c74-b37a-ccba7876e45a/2017-05-20_1852.png) to minimize interference with other programs, but it still has problems. For instance, if I am using the command prompt and activate the mic then `^C` will be entered.

Is there a way to create a new input value that I could map to my mouse then bind to an application that wouldn't be used by any other application?

I am using a Razar Taipan mouse with Razer Synapse software on Windows 7. The VoIP software I'm using is Discord, but I'm open to using a different app.

Comment: Some mouse software like [Logitech setpoint](http://support.logitech.com/en_nz/article/Configure-Application-Specific-settings-with-Logitech-Options-software) can assign app specified hotkeys. A general approach is to use autohotkey, write your own code to [handle different window](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActive.htm) and assign the mouse to that program.

Comment: Is there a specific reason this is tagged with [discord] and [razer-synapse]? If that Razer is the specific mouse you're using, you should mention it in the question

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I've updated the question

Comment: @Chris.C That's exactly the feature I'm looking for, too bad Razer doesn't currently support it. I'm going to look into autohotkey a bit now.